# Android 4.0 keyboard issue in emulator.?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am tried an app in android icecream sandwich emulator. My app is having some activities with some text box's. now the problem is when i am tapping on the text box the soft keypad is not appearing.And i checked it in Google maps application there too it is not displaying any key pad is there any problem in  android 4.0 with soft keypad???

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Fixed !

Edit your AVD, add "Keyboard Support" and change the value to no.

Restart your AVD making sure that you wipe user data. Your keyboard will popup now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did something similar

open ADV manger, Edit my ADV

just uncheck **"Hardware Keyboard Present"**