# Android 4.0.3 emulator will not display on-screen keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have tried everything, and I cant get my emulator on android 4.0.3 to show me the on-screen keyboard when I type into an EditText. Any ideas? I've tried creating an emulator of a different resolution (as suggested in another post) to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and fixed it by the solution provided here:

[Android 4.0 keyboard issue in emulator.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885563/android-4-0-keyboard-issue-in-emulator)