# Android emulator not shown soft keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have one edittext on my application and i want soft keyboard on emulator. But problems is its not showing keyboard.
I have tried so many things but its not use full to me :-

**first**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(tee_tea_edit_text, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

**second**

alredy click on this

```
Edit your AVD, add "Keyboard Support" and change the value to no.

Restart your AVD making sure that you wipe user data. Your keyboard will popup now.
```

So many things try but not use full to me.

[How can I make the Android emulator show the soft keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238769/how-can-i-make-the-android-emulator-show-the-soft-keyboard)

[Android 4.0 keyboard issue in emulator.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885563/android-4-0-keyboard-issue-in-emulator)

My avd image is below:-

[image: avd pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well You can try to Edit your AVD and set both :

`Keyboard Lid Support` and `Keyboard Support` to `YES`

Then restart your AVD. May be it will work.

Comment: you can uncheck the Checkbox that says : "Hardware Keyboard Present" and then restart your AVD.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Android Virtual Device, select your decide and uncheck the Checkbox that says : "Hardware Keyboard Present" and then restart your AVD

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

in your  tag in the layout.